# Get current authentication scheme in ASP.NET core 2

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, openid

I am currently struggling with an Asp.net core 2 application which uses two openid providers for authentication, mapped to two different Authentication Schemes (with different names).

The problem I am facing is trying to logout of the specific scheme that is currently being used. For example, if I support both Google and Facebook authentication, I need to understand which scheme is currently being used, and call the `SignOut` method indicating the correct scheme. This allows me to clear the local cookies and also redirect the user to the external identity provider and logout.

The thing is that I am not able to find a `GetCurrentScheme()` sort of function so that I can use to then specify the scheme in the `SignOut` method. I am sure I am missing something basic...

Answer (score 4):

There does not seem be any direct way to find current scheme. Here is a crude way:

```
private readonly IAuthenticationSchemeProvider authenticationSchemeProvider;
...
foreach(var scheme in authenticationSchemeProvider.GetRequestHandlerSchemesAsync()){
    var authResult = await context.AuthenticateAsync(scheme.Name);
    if(authResult.Succeeded)
        // this is the scheme that was used for authentication
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question, but I finally put the authentication scheme in the claims collection in my `SignIn` method :

```
claims.Add(new Claim(ClaimTypes.AuthenticationMethod, authenticationScheme));
```

So, in the `SignOut` method, I can retrieve the authentication scheme :

```
var authenticationScheme = HttpContext.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.AuthenticationMethod);
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a request feature that lets you find out which authentication scheme authenticated the user.

`this.HttpContext.Features.Get<IAuthenticateResultFeature>().AuthenticateResult?.Ticket?.AuthenticationScheme`

With Open Id Connect (and OAuth) based providers they generally use cookie based authentication for the SignedIn scheme so be careful with that. A lot of the aspnet core ones (and aspnet contrib) also put a value in the AuthenticationProperties called `.AuthScheme` which can also tell you which scheme authenticated the user.

Answer (score 1):

`IAuthenticationHandler` has also `Task InitializeAsync(AuthenticationScheme scheme, HttpContext context)`. It is called before `AuthenticateAsync` scheme name is here in first parameter.

Comment: That may be. But how does the developer take advantage of this in order to retrieve the current scheme already established?