# In .NET Core, How to configure specific authentication scheme per action and still use identity in middleware?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, authentication, .net-core, authorization

In my .NET Core service I configured 2 authentication schemes with wrappers of the built-in authentication extensions.

Using these 2 schemes, I defined per Controller/Action the authentication scheme I want to be used (allowed).
The problem is, that because there is no default authentication scheme defined in `.AddAuthentication`  **- then I can't use the User's claims in a middleware that gathers data from identity.**

(if I define default it runs the default as well, even when it is not needed)

---

How can this be done? (using `User.Claims` in a middleware - when the scheme is known to the app only on the endpoints? in the example it is called - **MiddlewareThatUsesUserClaims**)

Thanks!

---

*In ConfigureServices:*

```
services.AddAuthentication(/* defaultScheme: not defined */)
  .AddAzureAdBearer()
  .AddUserContextAzureAdBearer(configuration, "AadUserAuthentication")
  .AddAppContextAzureAdBearer(configuration, "AadApplicationAuthentication");

services.AddAuthorization();
services.AddCustomAuthorization(); // some custom handlers
```

*In Configure:*

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseMiddleware<MiddlewareThatUsesUserClaims>(); // *User.Claims is not populated here*
app.UseAuthorization(); // Update: replacing the order with my middleware doesn't work
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
```

*In Controller:*

```
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AadAuthentication.AppContextScheme)]
    [Route("api-that-accepts-app-context-tokens")]
    public async Task<OkObjectResult> App()
    {
         var tid = User.GetTenantId(); // works
    }

    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = AadAuthentication.UserContextScheme)]
    [Route("api-that-accepts-user-context-tokens")]
    public async Task<OkObjectResult> User()
    {
         var tid = User.GetTenantId(); // works
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

**To access claims in the middleware:**

Please, change the calling order in your *Configure* to:

```
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseMiddleware<MiddlewareThatUsesUserClaims>();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { endpoints.MapControllers(); });
```

The middlewares are called according to this order, so this may allow the fulfillment of `httpContext.User.Claims` in your `MiddlewareThatUsesUserClaims`. This worked in an example of mine.

---

**If you want to identify the auth scheme the client may be using, or if the client has claims:**

You may check the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54832713/get-current-authentication-scheme-in-asp-net-core-2), or simply look for the values in `httpContext.User.Claims`.

---

**If you want to have several default authentication schemes:**

After adding the authentication schemes in *ConfigureServices*, do you declare something like below?

```cs
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    var defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
        AadAuthentication.UserContextScheme,
        AadAuthentication.AppContextScheme);
    defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder = 
        defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    options.DefaultPolicy = defaultAuthorizationPolicyBuilder.Build();
});
```

According to the example in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-5.0#use-multiple-authentication-schemes), this is required.

They also point out that an [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/26002) was found related with the version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer`.

Cheers :)

Comment: I use the default authorization and some custom policy handlers:

`services.AddAuthorization();
services.AddCustomAuthorization();`

But authorization happens only after authentication right?
I am not sure it should affect

Comment: updated the question a bit to better explaining myself. thanks for assisting!

Comment: you're welcome :) ok, I will change my answer accordingly

Comment: but yes, authentication happens firstly, it is when the client provides the token to the app (the token is saying who the client is)

Comment: hey thanks for the help, this still doesn't work.
The User identity is not populated in my middleware, even though it is after `.UseAuthorization`.
I am still able to use it in the controller.

Comment: in your ConfigureServices, do you perform this `services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`? what .NET Core version are you using?

Comment: Yes I am performing this. .NET Core 3.1